# Super slow kernel startup

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, kernel

My Samsung series 5 notebook (i5, 500gb hdd, 4gb ram) has a super slow boot for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (I have a dual boot Windows 10 - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

I write:

```
systemd-analyze
```

Output:

> Startup finished in 41min 44.874s (kernel) + 36.641s (userspace) = 42min 21.516s

What can I do?